# Is it possible: Automator workflow for date based file import?

Tags: video, automator, photos, import

I'd like to know if the following is possible with Automator.

I want to be able to move any files, but in my special case videos and photos, from any possible device ( iPhone, iPad, SD card, but perhaps also from other directories) to my NAS, ordered by date.
Each file type should have a separate directory, eg.

```
NAS://imported/video 
NAS://imported/photos
```

What it should also do: within those separate directories, there should be a folder for each date a photo or video will be moved to(and it would also be important that you can customize the date format to `yy-mm-dd` , `dd-mm-yy` or the like, before you run the workflow )

```
NAS://imported/video/2014-11-04 
NAS://imported/video/2014-11-05
```

Now every video made on november the 5th should be moved to `NAS://imported/video/2014-11-05/video_file1.mp4`

I know that it is no problem to move files by type into certain folders, but I dont know how to create date-specific folders for each file before the move-command....

I'm on MacOS 10.10 (Yosemite)

Comment: This will be difficult to achieve with only Automator actions. You will likely need some shell script or another scripting language embedded within a **Run Script** action. Are you comfortable with shell script, AppleScript, or another language?

Comment: Oh what a pity... Well i know some (Korn-)Shell, but not enough to Code something for this use case. Depends on how much world be Automator and how much Shell. But what i reilly not Understand ist hat there is no native OS Solution for Mobbing files likes this (not even in a picture importer like Image Capture).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be difficult with Automator but it is possible. You will need to augment your Automator workflow with **Run Script** steps involving some other scripting language. That language can be shell script, AppleScript, or another command line capable tool such as perl.

Alternatively, you may find a third party tool like [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) is able to help:

> **Hazel** watches whatever folders you tell it to, automatically organizing your files according to the rules you create. It features a rule interface similar to that of Apple Mail so you should feel right at home.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to try Hazel, that might be just what i was looking for.